# GooglePlus Login Using Swift Not working

Tags: swift, google-oauth, google-signin

I am trying swift for the first time and want to create app with Facebook and google plus login.

I am able to do Facebook login using swift but not getting any step by step way to add google login with it.

So far i have written a sample code as below:

I have first screen with button, on click on it leads to google login page-

```
import UIKit

class GooglePlusLogin: UIViewController,GPPSignInDelegate {

//var signIn: GPPSignIn?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    var signIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
    //var signIn:GPPSignIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = true
    signIn?.clientID = "25344945xxxx-u4ou9si6v9qrr1ogmqactepxxxxxbg9s.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    signIn?.scopes = [kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin]
    signIn?.delegate = self
    signIn?.authenticate()

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
//MARK: G+

func finishedWithAuth(auth: GTMOAuth2Authentication!, error: NSError!) {

}

func didDisconnectWithError(error: NSError!) {

}


}
```

Whenever I clicks on that button it gives me error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM
>   gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fb58a716480'

Where I am doing wrong? I have added all frameworks with proper client id.

Comment: Check this link,, i will help you
http://grandbig.github.io/blog/2015/03/15/gtm-oauth2-in-swift/

Comment: @aBilal17  as far as i know.. we don't have to provide client secret to allow sign in with google in our system and in above link , it has given to add client secret, why?

Comment: The method which you are using surely reject your app from apple

Comment: That why i have sent you the other method,, there is client secret bellow the clientId in developer.google account under you application.

Comment: ok.. bt the code which i got is working for many people so , i just want to know that why apple will reject it?

Comment: I have got this error from apple few days ago.
10.6: Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or less than very good, it may be rejected
10.6

We found the following issues with the user interface of your app:

The app opens a web page in mobile Safari for logging in to Google plus, then returns the user to the app. The user should be able log in without opening Safari first.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't use cocoapods to install the library ? I got the same error.

You'd have to use the -ObjC linker flag to get it working, otherwise some objc categories from the framework are missing. But it broke other libraries for me so I gave up and used pods.

Here's a step by step tutorial: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating